# How to I add preview text on top of keyboard layout in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard-events

I want to show preview text on top of keyboard like this:

[image]

How do I solve with this problem?

Comment: All time thought, that it is UITextField with proper constraints to be under keyboard

Comment: iOS doesn't provide this type of Keyboard by default. You need to create the   view with subviews as textView and buttons as per mentioned in image. And then using keyboard notification event you can manipulate the created view.

Answer (score 2):

**I think this is what you want :**

[image]

**Code :**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let viewAcc = UIView()
        viewAcc.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 50)
        viewAcc.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

        let newTF = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 2, y: 10, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 75 , height: 30))
        newTF.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        newTF.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.none

        let btnDone = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: newTF.frame.size.width + 10, y: 5, width: 45, height: 30 ))
        btnDone.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        btnDone.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)

        viewAcc.addSubview(newTF)
        viewAcc.addSubview(btnDone)
        self.mytextField.inputAccessoryView = viewAcc
    }
```

**Reference:**

[Apple Doc Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiresponder/1621119-inputaccessoryview)

Answer (score 0):

@dahiya_boy's method is much better i guess. but if you need alternative way...

you can observe on this notifications and show or hide a label that show a preview of text.

```
 // this one trigger keyboardWillShow when keyboard is shown to user
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

 // this one trigger keyboardWillHide when keyboard is dismissing
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

and in function keyboardWillShow you can display a label for preview on top of the keyboard.

```
func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
        if let userInfo = sender.userInfo {
            if let keyboardHeight = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue().size.height {
                // keyboard height is available you can use it to put image in view
            }
        }
}




func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
    // you can hide the label here
}
```