# WPF: Show Text on top of Microsoft Surface Virtual Keyboard for Windows 10 / 11

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, virtual-keyboard

I finished the touch support for my `WPF`-Application. If I touch a `TextBox` the standard virtual keyboard pops up on my surface and I can use it as expected.
[image]

But my application is allways fullscreen and the keyboard overlays a big party of my application. So sometimes it is in front of the used `TextBox` - so you cant really see what you are writing, because its hidden behind the virtual keyboard.

So how can i configure my virtual keyboard on my Windows Surface to have a Preview-Textbox like this:

[image]

Best case:
Its just a configuration to show it. I dont want to change the style or the default behaviour of this standard mechanism of my winodws surface.

Comment: Show us your XAML declaration containing the virtual keyboard.

Comment: Well, this looks like a personalization setting in Windows.  Have a look here: https://www.howtogeek.com/746340/how-to-change-touch-keyboard-themes-on-windows-11/#:~:text=In%20Windows%20Settings%2C%20select%20the,themes%20that%20you%20can%20choose.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I made no configuration inside my wpf app. It is just working automaticly on windows surface. But i can add some.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I only see color settings, but nothing to show the Preview.

Comment: Where did you get the picture for the Preview-Textbox from?

Comment: From Google - just a random keyboard with a preview.

Comment: Link, please. ..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44104816/how-to-i-add-preview-text-on-top-of-keyboard-layout-in-ios

Comment: OK, a couple of observations.

Comment: 1.  That's an IOS virtual keyboard.  A Google Image Search confirms this.

Comment: 2.  AFAIK the virtual keyboard that comes with the Surface doesn't allow the kind of customization (i.e. adding a textbox) you want.  If you need this, you will most likely need to roll your own WPF keyboard.

Comment: consider to create your own Pop up dialog containing a textbox preview. Its still windows and windows is just not as touch optimized as iOS or Android